# preg_match does not match regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, match, preg-match-all

I am trying to scrape 10 digit numbers from a website with regex and pregmatch. So far have not been able to get any results. It matches when I use regular characters like in the first two commented out $regex variables. But not when I use regex as in the other ones.

I have checked all other similar questions here. Yet haven't been able to understand why the following regex script outputs empty array like

array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }

CODE

```
<?php 
$data=file_get_contents("http://www.landshoppe.com/contactus");
//$regex = '/9833157945/';
//$regex = "/<a href='(.+?)'>/";
$regex='/^[0-9]\b\d{10}\b$/';

//$regex='/\(?\s?[2-9][0-9]{2}[(\s?\)?\s?)\-\.]{1,3}[0-9]{3}[\s\-\.]{1,3}[0-9]{10}/';
//$regex='/\[^\d\]/';
preg_match_all($regex,$data,$match);
//preg_match_all($regex,"9898989898 kmllkj 9087654567 kjhkhkhj 9043567898 hkhkjhkjhk",$match);
//  var_dump($data);
//  echo htmlspecialchars($data);

var_dump($match); 
echo "<p></p>";
foreach($match as $m){foreach($m as $ma){echo $ma."<br>";}}
//echo $match[1];
?>
```

If you observe, I have been trying all kinds of regex combinations and none giving result.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this expression: `/^[0-9]{5}$/` will match strings which are *entirely* made up from 5 digits. The `^` and `$` instruct the engine to match from the beginning and keep on going until the end. This is different from the expression of `/9833157945/`, which denotes a particular 10 digit number.

You would need to change it at least to `\d{10}` to match 10 digits. If the digits must not be contained within other strings, that is, `foo0123456789`, you could use the `\b` tag: `\b\d{10}\b`.

Comment: Hi...@npinti very sorry. Am very bad at regex. the{5} was an oversight.  I have edited the question to for 10 digits..and also added the \b\d . Am not sure if I have done it right. But still gives me empty array.

Comment: @user3526204: Can you please update your question with a sample value for `$data`?

Comment: $data is what we get from file_get_contents of the url. It basically the source file of the page.

Answer (score 0):

'/[0-9]\d{10}/' solved my issue ! It now matches all the 10 digit numbers !

Thanks all.